# Helper function to iterate over an array in a rotating fashion

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of ids for carousel items

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
```

Lets say I want to start showing slide with id=2 then on clicking next button it shows id=3. if it reaches id=4 and click next it shows id=1. (Kind of rotating)
Clicking previous button should do the same on different direction.

I am wondering if there is any method in lodash or es6 that gives me this functionality so I don't write logic for it in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the cyclic calculation you can use the native js [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator:

```
(currentIndex + 1) % arr.length // currentIndex is the position in the array
```

```js
const findNextIndex = (currentIndex, arr) => (currentIndex + 1) % arr.length;

const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
let current = 2; // the start position

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const show = document.getElementById('show');

show.innerText = arr[current];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  current = findNextIndex(current, arr);
  
  show.innerText = arr[current];
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">next</button>

<div id="show"></div>
```